# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Строчка кода на которой выходит ошибка:

```
if df.iloc[-1:]['crossover'] == 'bullish crossover':
```

Значение в указанной ячейке "None"
Пробовал вариант

```
if bool(df.iloc[-1:]['crossover'] == 'bullish crossover') == True
```

Ошибка аналогична

Comment: это не ячейка, это ряд. ваш локатор [-1:] прямо об этом заявляет. а ошибка прямо подсказывает, как этого избежать. либо указывайте в индекс-локаторе не только строку, но и столбец, либо используйте метод any.